# d3js bar chart race ... restarting animation

Tags: animation, d3.js, charts

Recently I found a very nice code ([d3js bar chart race](https://github.com/ytdec/bar-chart-race/blob/master/index.html)) on github.

I would like to change this code so I can apply a delay of some seconds when the animation stops and then restart from the begining, keeping the animation in a loop.

In the source code, I can see the following code:

```
if(year == 2001) ticker.stop(); // stop the animation
```

Now, can I use `d3.time`/`d3.settimeout`/`d3.interval`/`?` to this behavior?
What is the best way for achieving it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, @Daniel Santos.
It would be nice if you added some `code blocks` and made your question clearer so everybody can understand. Have a nice day!

Comment: reference source code: https://github.com/ytdec/bar-chart-race/blob/master/index.html

Comment: if(year == 2002) {
     year = 2000;
     var interval = d3.timeout(callback, 10000, 10000);
     return;
     }
// including this the animation restart but the delay isn't working !